# How to set working directory on FTPusing FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm using java FTPClient for FTPconnection. This library has `storeFile` method for saving a file on FTP. I use it like this:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
//code for connection and login
...
ftpClient.storeFile("test.jpg", stream); //stream is an InputStream
```

Now, I need to set working directory on FTP. For example I want to save my `.jpg` in the specific folder. Is `ftpClient.storeFile("1/test.jpg", stream);` correct? 
Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should call `FTPClient#changeWorkingDirectory()` ([the docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#changeWorkingDirectory(java.lang.String))) prior to `storeFile()`.